# Error in main subscripted value in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm new to C and I'm trying to calculate the kinetic energy from certain values (px and py) but my routine accuses always as main mistake *subscripted value is neither array nor pointer vector nor*. Can anyone help me because all I know I've tried.

The error occurs in the kinetic function

thanks

My routine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef RAN2_H_
#define RAN2_H_

void UniformBox(long, long *, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double *);

void kinetic(long, double, double, double); 

#endif /* RAN2_H_ */

#include "ran2.h"

float ran2(long*);

void UniformBox(long n, long *idum, double L, double p0, double *rx, double *ry, double *px, double *py){


    long i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        rx[i] = ((double)ran2(idum))*L;
        ry[i] = ((double)ran2(idum))*L;
        px[i] = ((double)ran2(idum) -.5)*2*p0;
        py[i] = ((double)ran2(idum) -.5)*2*p0;
    }



    return;
}


void kinetic(long n, double x, double y, double kint){

    long i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

        kint[i] = (x*x)+(y*y);
    }

    return;
 }


void UniformBox(long, long *, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double *);

void kinetic(long n, double x, double y, double kint);


int main(){

    long i, n, seed, idum;
    double *rx, *ry, *px, *py;
    double L, p0, kint;

    n = 1000;
    L = 2.0;
    p0 = 1.22;
    seed = 10;
    idum = -seed;

    FILE *init = fopen("initialPosition.dat", "w");

    rx = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    ry = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    px = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    py = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));

    UniformBox(n, &idum, L, p0, rx, ry, px, py);
    kinetic(n, px, py, kint);
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", rx[i], ry[i], px[i], py[i], kint[i]);
        fprintf(init,"%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", rx[i], ry[i], px[i], py[i]);
    }

    fclose(init);

    free(rx);
    free(ry);
    free(px);
    free(py);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message comes with a line number; please mark the line in question. This also seems to be a syntax error, so there's probably no need to post the whole program.

Comment: The error is also obvious: `kint` is a scalar double, which can't be subscripted with `[]`. If you want `kint`to be an array, treat it like the other double arrays you have defined in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the compile errors. A few things to note.

I removed multiple incompatible function prototypes.

Aside from `kinetic`'s `kint` needing to be a pointer, `x` and `y` needed to be pointers. Note that this is conjecture on my part, based on the totality of the code. Also note the change inside the loop from `x` to `x[i]`. Otherwise, things didn't make sense [to me].

In `main`, I added a `malloc` for `kint`

Anyway, here's the code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef RAN2_H_
#define RAN2_H_

float ran2(long *);

#endif /* RAN2_H_ */

//#include "ran2.h"

void
UniformBox(long n, long *idum, double L, double p0, double *rx, double *ry,
    double *px, double *py)
{

    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rx[i] = ((double) ran2(idum)) * L;
        ry[i] = ((double) ran2(idum)) * L;
        px[i] = ((double) ran2(idum) - .5) * 2 * p0;
        py[i] = ((double) ran2(idum) - .5) * 2 * p0;
    }

    return;
}

void
kinetic(long n, double *x, double *y, double *kint)
{

    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        kint[i] = (x[i] * x[i]) + (y[i] * y[i]);
    }

    return;
}

int
main()
{

    long i, n;
    long seed, idum;
    double *rx, *ry;
    double *px, *py;
    double L, p0;
    double *kint;

    n = 1000;
    L = 2.0;
    p0 = 1.22;
    seed = 10;
    idum = -seed;

    FILE *init = fopen("initialPosition.dat", "w");

    rx = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    ry = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    px = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    py = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));
    kint = (double *) malloc((double) n * sizeof(double));

    UniformBox(n, &idum, L, p0, rx, ry, px, py);
    kinetic(n, px, py, kint);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", rx[i], ry[i], px[i], py[i], kint[i]);
        fprintf(init, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", rx[i], ry[i], px[i], py[i]);
    }

    fclose(init);

    free(rx);
    free(ry);
    free(px);
    free(py);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C , you must pass arrays into a function by reference. Thus, your function header should be

```
void kinetic(long n, double x, double y, double * kint);
```

You could also use the [] notation like is suggested in the comments.

Comment: You're not wrong but he never declares kint as an array or pointer anywhere in his code.

Comment: I did as I indicated and continues giving error:

####################################################
> teste.c:74:5: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘kinetic’
     kinetic(n, px, py, kint);
     ^
####################################################

>teste.c:37:6: note: expected ‘double’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
 void kinetic(long n, double x, double y, double * kint){

####################################################

>teste.c:37:6: note: expected ‘double’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
 void kinetic(long n, double x, double y, double * kint){
      ^